# I use jersey + protobuf, How can I pass a meaningful error message back to client?

Tags: jersey, protocol-buffers

How can I pass a meaningful error message back to client? I can implement the ExceptionMapper to produce meaningful error message. 
But how can I have writer to pass the message back to client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used jersey personally, but my **general** approach here would be to simply include the result-state (including error message) in the returned message, i.e.

```
message GetCustomerResult {
    optional string errorMessage = 1;
    optional Customer customer = 2;
}
```

or similar, such that all your messages have a consistent way to report failure. If your error state is more than just a string, you could declare a `message` for that, and include it on all results, so you can just pass that to any shared error-handling code.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw WebApplicationException which takes Response in a constructor and gets mapped by Jersey automatically to that response. You can put the meaningful message into the response body.

Comment: is it the same to implement ExceptionMapper and construct the Response int toResponse method?